# error in swift when using loadDataFromURL in Xcode 8.3

Tags: swift, loaddata

I am testing this code from Ray Wenderlich to download data from URL. I got it working, but I updated to Xcode 8.3 and now suddenly it does not work any longer. I got the advise back that my problem has already been resolved in the following link [SWIFT: Error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42436189/swift-error-exc-bad-instruction), however, when adding the try! option or adding a do-catch as suggested, this did not make the error go away. Here is the code again:

```
class func loadDataFromURL(_ url: URL, completion:@escaping (_ data: Data?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {


            let session = URLSession.shared
                // Use NSURLSession to get data from an NSURL



            let loadDataTask = try! session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
              if let responseError = error {
                completion(nil, responseError)
                print("something went wrong 1")

                //activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
              } else if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                if httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
                 let statusError = NSError(domain:"com.raywenderlich", code:httpResponse.statusCode, userInfo:[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "HTTP status code has unexpected value."])
                  completion(nil, statusError)
                } else {
                  completion(data, nil)
                    //activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                }
              }

            } as! (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)  //error is thrown here!!

        loadDataTask.resume()     
}
}
```

When I run the code I get the error code in the last line: "Thread 1: EXEC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)"

Comment: It should be Error instead of NSError

Comment: yes, this worked. Once I changed to Error I could then leave out the down casting. Not sure why? Anyway, it works. Can you please make this your official answer so that I can tick it off. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I tried to parsing data Asynchronously it got rid of the error and worked fine. I'm not sure but it may solve your problem,too.